# Mails not going to Cc and Bcc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

The following is my mail sending code in c#. Mail goes to address but doesnt go to Cc and Bcc address sometimes. It terminates.

```
     MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
            MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
            Msg.From = fromMail;
            foreach (var address in toEmail.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(address));
            }

            if (ccEmail != "" && bccEmail != "")
            {
                foreach (var address1 in ccEmail.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    Msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(address1));
                }

                foreach (var address2 in bccEmail.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    Msg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(address2));
                }
            }
 SmtpClient a = new SmtpClient("smptserver");
            a.Send(Msg);
```

Can somebody help me to know why it is not going to Cc and Bcc?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if a CC **and** a BCC address available before sending to either of them. So you are effectively only sending CC / BCC if both are available. Sending only to CC or only to BCC will not work with your code. Is this intended?

If you want to send to either CC or BCC (depending on what is available), check them separately if they are empty

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccEmail))
  {
      foreach (var address1 in ccEmail.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
     {
        Msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(address1));
     }
  }

  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bccEmail))
  {
      foreach (var address2 in bccEmail.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
      {
         Msg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(address2));
      }
  }
```

Comment: eventhough i have address in cc and bcc mail is not going to it. only in to address it is going

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint and check the values for `ccEmail` and `bccEmail`? What are their values?